# cURL cannot connect using PHP but can connect through IDE

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, ftps

Note: I changed the IP address to "*" for security purposes.

I'm trying to connect to an FTPS server port 990 using cURL but it's returning an error below (server is in AWS)

```
*   Trying **.***.***.***...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to **.***.***.*** port 990 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to **.***.***.*** port 990: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
```

PHP function **ftp_ssl_connect()** is also not working

I tried to connect using IDE with below cURL command and it's working just fine

```
curl -vvv --user username:password ftp://**.***.***.***:990
```

There's also no issue using telnet

```
telnet **.***.***.*** 990
```

Not sure what's the issue as I'm not very proficient on servers.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: the target server is running an IP whitelist or an IP blacklist, either your AWS ip is in the blacklist, or your IDE's IP is in the whitelist. i'm guessing it's a blacklist.

Comment: Hi @hanshenrik, thanks for the reply! I just confirmed that the server where I'm trying to connect is not blacklisting any IP address.